# How did Adebisi make his hat hang on his head?

Tags: props, oz

In the TV show Oz, Simon Adebisi is very often shown with a hat hanging on the top of his head. It looks like it will almost fall.

[image: Adebisi]

I remember it being discussed sometimes in the show, but can't recall exactly  what they said about it.

Is this explained? Maybe there is a "behind-the-scenes" explanation by actors?

Comment: LOL!  I was just re-watching this show over the past few weeks and was wondering the same thing!

Comment: [Ask Dumbo](http://www.etonline.com/news/2015/06/24159404/GIF_disney_pixar_tears_dumbo.gif). ;)

Comment: @Walt, or [Homer](http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5018/5518123088_2bcb1df220.jpg)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is an [interview](http://www.mensfitness.com/content/training-ozs-simon-adebisi) in Men's Fitness where the actor, Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje explains how the hat stayed on his head:

> But the weirdest thing about Adebisi was how he wore his trademark 
>   knit hat. The thing stayed perched on the corner of his head and 
>   seemed to never move. Anyone who ever watched the show had to wonder 
>   how he kept it up there. Turns out, there wasn’t much of a secret to 
>   be revealed.
>
> **I just put it on my head and it stays there,** he says. **People think
>   it’s Velcro or whatever. All it is is my bald head. You just stick it
>   on the corner. I could do a backflip and that baby wouldn’t move.**

Just another reason why Adebisi was the most badass character on Oz.
 He defied the laws of physics.

Comment: Maybe tiny hair can have a sort of velcro effect on wool...

Comment: Do you mean like stubble?  I can see that probably being true!

Comment: I Periodically shave my head. I can confirm it does hold fuzzy hats well. Actually, keeping your head completely smooth is a lot of work, you have to shave with a real razor (not an electric one) daily.

Answer (score 22):

I'm bald too and have insight on this issue because I tried to do it with multiple beanies (I really like OZ).

The secret is having a beanie that's made from a material that's a tiny bit rubbery, I had one from a sports store that felt like cotton but was stretchy and a bit rubbery feel, I rolled it up like Adebisi and it stuck on a clear shaven scalp like glue.